# How do I create a Multi-Tab statement in M365 excel

Tags: excel, comparison, uptime

I have 3 tables on 3 tabs I to do a countif, but preferably a vlookup for uptime.

I have a bit of a Problem I have 3 tables from 3 different pulls from my uptime runs, I so I end up with 3 tables in one xlsx My co workers then provide output from there sources and we have a combined document with easy logic to implement a check on Pcs. I want to compare the values and find the offline cell. I know command in the full versions of excel offer the ability's with ease, but in an all 365 environment, how is the best way to go about this?

this is what I got:

```
=countif(Table1[[#Headers],[PC1Output]],Table2[[#Headers],[PC2Output]],Table3[[#Headers],[IP3 Output]])
```

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Val 1 | ON |
| Val 3 | ON |

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Val 3 | ON |
| Val 1 | ON |

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Val 3 | ON |
| Cell 3 | Off |

I understand I could answer this with different application like PowerBi But its faster to use a formula in most cases.

Comment: Please share your expected result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.